# Strange behavior in Fal (Haskell library)

Tags: haskell, animation

I have difficulties with some code. I follow the excellent Haskell School of Expression by Paul Hudak and cannot debug a program. It is an exercise where I must do a Paddleball (exercise 15.1). I am trying to make the ball remain in the center of the screen before a left press. But it breaks the program which works fine if I remove the part `0 'untilB' lbp ->>` in both xnormalSpeed and ynormalSpeed . The ball will not bounce following the x axis (even though the boolean xbounce becomes true). The value of xnormalSpeed always stays equal to 2.

```
xpos, ypos :: Behavior Float
xpos = integral xnormalSpeed
ypos = integral ynormalSpeed

xnormalSpeed, ynormalSpeed :: Behavior Float
xnormalSpeed = 0 `untilB` lbp ->> (vel `stepAccum` when xbounce ->> negate)
ynormalSpeed = 0 `untilB` lbp ->> (vel `stepAccum` when ybounce ->> negate)

xbounce, ybounce :: Behavior Bool

vel :: Behavior Float
vel = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

the `sample` event might be useful:

```
module Ex1 where
import Fal

ex = test (paint color2h circl)
circl = Fal.translate pt (Fal.ell 0.2 0.2)
pt = (xpos, 0)
xpos = 0.0 `untilB` lbp ->> (0.0 `stepAccum` sample ->> (+0.01))
```